# Python django: filtering a table based on a criteria on another table

Tags: database, python-3.x, django-models

I'm going to filter objects in a table based on whether a field in one of the foreign keys (in another table) contains a string. Consider the following tables:

```
class Students(models.Model):
      StudentID = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
      Teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teachers)

class Teachers(models.Model):
      TeacherID = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
      TeacherName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I want to have a queryset of students that their teachers name contains 'Sara'. Following code makes the queryset:

```
student_queryset = Students.objects.all()
for student in student_queryset:
     if str(student.Teacher.TeacherName).find('Sara') == -1:
          student_queryset = student_queryset.exclude(StudentID = student.StudentID)
```

The problem is that this code is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It was just a row:

```
student_queryset = Students.objects.filter(Teacher__TeacherName__contains = 'Sara')
```